# Argparse pattern where input filenames are given through a file or a list of filenames on the command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Does argparse support a pattern such as:

```
foo.py {-f list_of_filenames.txt|file [file ...]}
```

I achieve this at the moment with the following argparse definition:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--file", "-f")
parser.add_argument("files", nargs="*")
```

and performing the mutual exclusivity + required check in my code rather than letting argparse do the check.

Can argparse handle a pattern of this sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argparse` takes `fromfile-prefix-chars` parameter

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars

So if the filenames are in a file, one name per line

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
>>> parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
>>> parser.parse_args(['@filenames.txt'])
```

Will read the names from the file.  It puts them in the `sys.argv` list just as though you had entered them on the command line.

Comment: Great! Works great for my use case! Thanks.